# Strange use of void in c++ code

Tags: c++, std

Here is some code from a presentation about async tasks in C++

```
template <class T> class Future<T>{
  //something
  void  foo(std::function<void(T)> cb);    
  //something
};
```

What does `void(T)` mean?

Comment: void(T) is a function signature (type)

Comment: void is the return type, as you can [read in the reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function).

Answer (score 7):

> What does `void(T)` mean?

That specifies a function type; specifically, a function taking a single parameter of type `T`, and returning nothing. In general, type specifiers for complex types look like their corresponding variable declarations, but without a variable name:

```
void f(T); // declare a function
void(T)    // specifier for a function type

int a[42]; // declare an array
int[42]    // specifier for an array type
```

In this case, the function type is used to specify the signature of the function-call operator of the `std::function`:

```
void operator()(T);
```

so that the function object can be used like a function with that type:

```
T some_t;
cb(some_t); // usable like a function taking `T`
```

Answer (score 6):

`cb` is a `std::function` whose `operator()` takes a `T` and returns `void`.

Answer (score 1):

void(T) is a function signature (type)

Note the signature is not a pointer to a function, not a pointer to a member function and no lambda:

```
#include<functional>

void a(int) {}
struct B {
    void f(int) {}
};


int main() {
    std::function<void(int)> fn;
    fn = a;

    B b;
    fn = std::bind(&B::f, b, std::placeholders::_1);

    auto lambda = [](int) {};
    fn = lambda;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The explanation can be as follows based on the C++11 specifications : `A parameter list consisting of a single unnamed parameter of non-dependent type void is equivalent to an empty parameter list.`

void is not a valid argument type for a function, however T in void(T) is a dependent type, it depends on a template parameter. That way you can have no arguments in the function based on the parameter of the template.

Comment: That would (partly) explain what `void(void)` meant, but doesn't answer this question.

Comment: I am going to explain what I think, void is not a valid argument type for a function, however T in void(T) is a dependent type--it depends on a template parameter. That way you can have no arguments in the function based on the parameter of the template. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, the template would still be valid if instantiated with `T=void`, for the reason you describe. But that's got nothing to do with the question, which is "What does `void(T)` means?"

Comment: Understood, saw your answer to the post.